# Access VBA: Type mismatch on CurrentDb.OpenRecordset

Tags: ms-access, vba

In the following code I get the `compile error Type mismatch` when I am giving a value to vcount.

The code I use is:

```
Dim SQL As String
Dim vcount As Integer

SQL = " SELECT count(*) FROM [Data Processing List];"

vcount = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(SQL)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some alternative approaches.

Use **TableDefs** to count the number of rows within a specific table:

```
Dim vcount As Integer

vcount = CurrentDb.TableDefs("[Data Processing List]").RecordCount
```

Use **DCount**:

```
Dim vcount As Integer

vcount = DCount("*", "[Data Processing List]")
```

There's more methods.
Have a look at this quite interesting article that discusses several methods including performance results for small versus medium sized tables:

[MS Access – VBA – Get Record Count](https://www.devhut.net/2016/02/24/ms-access-vba-get-record-count/)

Comment: _DCount_ is the dead-simple method.

Answer (score 1):

`CurrentDb.OpenRecordset` returns a recordset, not a value.

If you want to access the value of a field of the recordset, you can do so by using the `.Value` property of the desired field in the fields collection:

```
vcount = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(SQL).Fields(0).Value
```